# Versioning and Optimistic Locking in Solr 4.0?

Tags: solr

I saw

> Versioning and Optimistic Locking – combined with real-time get, this
>   allows read-update-write functionality that ensures no conflicting
>   changes were made concurrently by other clients.

from http://searchhub.org/dev/2012/05/21/solr-4-preview/ and other sources. Although it is very interesting, there is **few other mentions** on this topic.

Can someone explain this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot fully explain this feature. But, here are some additional links from the Solr Issues and Wiki that provide more details. With the official release of Solr 4.0 today, I am hopeful that more details and examples of how these features work will begin to emerge.

- [SOLR-3178 - Versioning - optimistic locking](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3178)
- [Update Semantics](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Per%20Steffensen/Update%20semantics)
- [Real-Time Get](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/RealTimeGet?highlight=%28nosql%29)